# ASP .Net MVC Form not calling controller on submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having trouble getting my view to call the post method in my MVC Controller. When I click on the submit button, it does not call the Create method. I add a breakpoint, but it never gets to the code. I am assuming some error, but not sure how to see the error message.

Here is the View:

```
@model PersonViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm(PeopleControllerAction.Create, ControllerName.People, FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal row"> 
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
<div class="row panel radius">
    <div class="medium-2 columns">
        <h3>Contact Information</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="medium-10 columns">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="medium-6 columns">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                    <div>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>

// more fields removed for brevity

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Here is the controller:

```
public class PeopleController : Controller
{
    private IPersonService context { get; set; }

    public PeopleController(IPersonService context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

// POST: People/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "FirstName,LastName,Age,Email,Phone,City,State,HopeToReach,Story,Goal,Image")] PersonViewModel person)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                person.ImagePath = ImageUploader.UploadImage(person.Image);
            }
            catch (ArgumentException e)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, e.Message);
            }

            var id = await context.AddAsync(person);
            return RedirectToAction(PeopleControllerAction.Confirmation);
        }

        return View(person);
    }
}
```

Comment: Early question does your view actually have this code 
@using (Html.BeginForm(PeopleControllerAction.Create, ControllerName.People, FormMethod.Post))
{
}

Or does it say something like @using(Html.BeginForm("People","Create"...)

Comment: take a look into your renderized view and check on form element

Comment: I don't know for others Browsers but,
with firefox and firebug(add on) you can see every error in the browser console. (Client and Server side) 
maybe you should take a look
note: if you don't want firebug firefox's console also provide a network panel (ctrl+maj+K)

Comment: The form element is <form action="/" method="post"> which is I assume the problem. But even if I replace my constants with the actual controller and action name, it renders the same form element.

Comment: Can you post your route configuration?

Comment: Im using attribute routing. The method has no route. I think thats the problem

Comment: Yup, it needed a route

Answer (score -1):

This was resolved. The action in question did not have a route. I am using attribute routing.

Comment: You should include your example solution in your answer.

Comment: I agree. It would help if you include your solution here.

Comment: This was a year ago. I dont even have access to the code anymore